# Inaccurate tint of RatingBar using progressTint

Tags: android, android-layout, androidx, ratingbar

I figured that with `android:progressTint="@color/ratingColor"` on `AppCompatRatingBar`, I can change the color of filled stars. But then I noticed green color towards left edge of the filled star. I tried with other tints but can not get rid of that.

This is screen shot of AS Preview but issue remains the same when I run on the device.

Anyone faced this issue? How did you remove that unwanted green color of the edge?

[image: preview of review]

Zoomed in:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I guess I did not try all the tints when I posted the question.

I solved this with `android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/transparent"`.